# How to set kpi for SharePoint list to a date column which is going to expire?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I would like to set KPI indicator (red,green) to a date column in SharePoint 2013 which is going to expire today. If expires, need to set red color. How to achieve this? thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried searching for 'color today'?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JSlink by following

- Create a new JS file .
- paste the following code after modifying it with your columns names.
- upload it to Style library on SharePoint site

> ```
> (function () {
>
> var itemCtx = {};
>
>
> itemCtx.Templates = {};
>
> itemCtx.Templates.Header = “<div><b>Data</b></div><ul>”;
> itemCtx.Templates.Item = KPIIndecator;
> itemCtx.Templates.Footer = “</ul>”;
>
> itemCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
> itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;
>
> SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);
> })();
>
> function KPIIndecator(ctx) {
>
> var today = new Date();
>
> if (ctx.CurrentItem.date > today )
> {
> return “<li style=’background-color: green ;width: 300px;height: 24px;’>” +  ctx.CurrentItem.date+ “</li></span>”;
> }
>
> if (ctx.CurrentItem.date <= today )
> {
> return “<li style=’background-color: #4AA02C;width: 300px;height: 24px;’>” +  ctx.CurrentItem.date + “</li></span>”;
> }
>
>
> }
> ```

Continue steps in details [here](http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2015/03/sharepoint-2013-conditional-formatting-in-listviews/)

Comment: Hi Qassas, the link in your answer not working.

Comment: thank you for this hint I have updated the link , Take your time to test this solution. Please, upvote/set this as answer in case it's useful and helped you to solve your issue :) I am also here if you need more clarification, Respect your appreciation for my time :)